# C - Truncated char array input automatically assigned to next char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, c-strings

I've been trying to input 2 char arrays from user.

I want to truncate the input characters if they are more than specified length.
This is what I have done so far.

```
int main(){

    printf("Enter Password: ");
    char password[9]= {0};
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);


    printf("Enter key file path: ");
    char file_path[200];
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(file_path, sizeof(file_path), stdin);
    puts(file_path);

    return 0;

}
```

I get this output:

[image]

If I enter more than 8 chars, it automatically assigns charcaters above 8 to my `file_path`. It does not ask for the 2nd input!

PS: I tried `scanf("%8s", password)` instead of fgets. Same issue.

Please Help, Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it without the `flush`?

Comment: Once you read in 8 characters for the password (*please* tell me this isn't a security-critical application; that is not enough), the rest are still there. You need to discard the rest of the line before reading the key file path.

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes. Still same result.

Comment: @FiddlingBits have **you** read about `fflush`ing stdin having undefined behaviour

Comment: @DanielH yes, its a security critical (but my pet project so far). And I do want to discard the rest of the line in password. Thats exactly what I am trying to do. Thats why I put fflush there to clear out the input buffer.

Comment: Then you shouldn't discard any part of the password; you should let the user have a 300-byte password if they want. Don't impose arbitrary limits on passwords. If you must, at least make it long enough to fit in a decent pass phrase.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I believe I have read that. That's why I was asking OP. Why are you asking me?

Comment: @FiddlingBits omg indeed you did :D and I read incorrectly, sorry about that. Though it doesn't fix it either.

Comment: @DanielH I want to use it as a key for DES (Data Encryption Standard). 64-bit key size is a standard for DES. Cant use more than that.

Comment: @kernel 8 user-entered characters is not actually 64 bits of entropy (nobody is going to enter `\x07` and they *cannot* enter `\n`), and DES is broken and you shouldn't use it if you actually care about security.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala No problem. I forgive you. ;-)

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to write your own cryptography code. DES has been withdrawn and is no longer a NIST standard; you should use AES instead, or possibly something built using AES depending on the application. But you shouldn't write the AES code yourself, for several reasons (you might have bugs which were discovered in other code, you might be vulnerable to side-channel attacks, the library probably knows how to make it faster than you do, etc). Use a library, or the kernel cryptography API.

Comment: The security concerns of the other commentators are all valid, and you should seriously take them into mind. If you still wanna shoot yourself in the foot, you can use `int ch; while (ch = getchar() != '\n' && ch != EOF);` to flush the input after the first `fgets`.

Comment: @nullp0tr Thanks man! I know DES is broken but its hard to explain why I'm doing this. Can you explain how this flushes the input buffer? and why `fflush` wasn't working?

Comment: Thanks @DanielH! Appreciate it man.

Answer (score 1):

In OP's code, the input that does not fit in the first `fgets()` remains for subsequent input.  Better code would consume the entire line and detect if the line is excessively long.

Use `fgets()` with a long enough buffer to look for incomplete *line* input.
Read at least 2 more characters: extra character and `'\n'`.

---

Perhaps use your own `my_gets()` to read a line.

```
// Read a line
// If input, without the \n fits in the destination, return `s`
// else return NULL
// Conditions: line != NULL,  0 < sz <= INT_MAX
char *my_gets(char *line, size_t sz) {
  if (fgets(line, (int) sz, stdin) == NULL) {
    line[0] = '\0';
    return NULL; // EOF
  }

  size_t length = strlen(line);
  if (length > 0 && line[length - 1] == '\n') {
    line[--length] = '\0';  // Chop off \n
  } else if (length == sz - 1) {
    // Consume rest of line
    bool looped = false;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      looped = true;
    }
    if (looped) {
      return NULL; // Line too long
    }
  }
  return line;
}
```

Application

```
int main(void) {
    printf("Enter Password: ");
    char password[9];
    if (my_gets(password, sizeof password) == NULL) {
      return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }
    puts(password);

    printf("Enter key file path: ");
    char file_path[200];
    if (my_gets(file_path, sizeof file_path) == NULL) {
      return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }
    puts(file_path);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

From a security standpoint, good to scrub `password[]` and `line[]` after code is done with it.

```
memset(password, 0, sizeof password);
```

Yet the call to `fgets(), fgetc()` are themselves not so secure as they are not specified to "cover their tracks" as they return.  This is a deeper subject beyond this post.

Comment: Yeah I just added the the `consume rest of line` part. It was the necessary evil. 
The method is way too much complicated for reading a char array. 
Anyway, Thanks man, Appreciate it. :)